# 2015 Macbook Won't Turn On - Shows no sign of life

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, battery

I recently bought a 2015 Macbook from a friend, and after only a day of use, it won't turn on...

I shut down the Macbook with around 15% charge left on it, so initially I thought this to be a lack-of-charge issue, however I've had it plugged in for over 8 hours and still it doesn't turn on.

I've tried the Shift+Control+Power 10 second restart, along with the CMD+R+Power reset, but no signs of life.

The trackpad clicker doesn't click, and the caps lock button doesn't light up. The problem with this 'modern mac' is that it has no moving parts, so you can't hear it turn on!

Is there anything I can try before I take it into the Apple store?

Thanks

Comment: Go to the Apple Store. And don't try to turn it on again. This can be liquid in the MacBook which could destroy even more on every try. A friedn of mine had the same issue.Sometimes things like this can happen out of know where. A good advice: if things like this happen, Apple has an excellent Customer Service, you should call them as well to get help and an appointment.

Comment: All booked in at the Genius bar this evening. Thanks for the tips!